# React Navigation 4.x : Passing props to tabBarOnPress

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

MaterialTopTabNavigator in React Navigation 4.x

I want to show an alert to the user when he tries to navigate to other tabs (by swiping or by pressing the tab bar).

Scenario: While on a tab (which consists a form of TextInput fields), if a user tries to navigate to any other tab without saving the form, I need to show an Alert whether the user wants to save the form before moving to other tab.

I tried to handle it using the tabBarOnPress function of other tabs but can't pass props to check if the form is saved.

Also, I'm searching for an event which triggers a callback when a user swipes to navigate to other tabs.

Comment: You should be able to use `tabBarOnPress` along with a global state provider such as Redux to keep the `valid` state of the input form. You should be able to set `swipeEnabled` dynamically using the same property so the users can't swipe away from the screen.